# Publish via Facebook API: How to include link to original like Instagram does?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, indieweb

Typically when an application publishes to Facebook via the Graph API, Facebook includes a little link at the top of the news item indicating which application posted it, linking to the application's website.

I noticed recently that when Instagram shares a photo to Facebook the "Instagram" link at the top of the item points to the actual photo permalink `instagram.com/p/whatever` instead of just `instagram.com`.

Is it possible to set a custom URL per-post when publishing via the Graph API? Or some other mechanism? Or is this a special insider configuration for IG only?

[image: Instagram photo shared to FB]

Comment: This is a custom configuration for Instagram.